# Reference request: associative subalgebras of Cayley algebras are at most 4-dimensional

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, non-associative-algebras

By a Cayley algebra I mean an 8-dimensional algebra (over an arbitrary field) formed in the Cayley-Dickson process. (They are also called octonion algebras, but I prefer to reserve the term octonion for the real case.) An equivalent characterization is as a simple alternative algebra that is not associative.

Recently (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01268.pdf, Thm 6.6) I proved the statement in the title, which is intuitively clear in the division algebra case, but not so much in the split case where 3- and 6-dimensional subalgebras exist. (The split Cayley algebra even has a *commutative* three-dimensional subalgebra, whose six-dimensional Dickson double is associative, but luckily does not appear as a subalgebra of the split Cayley algebra.)

Anyway, the statement 'feels' like it has been proven already before in the 1950s by e.g. Zorn and I would be more than happy to replace my somewhat lengthy proof by a short reference. In my paper the theorem is just a small step in a bigger argument of which the proof only distracts.

Hence the question: **does the claim that associative subalgebras of Cayley algebras are at most 4-dimensional appear in the literature and if so: where?**

Comment: I thought that normed algebras follow basically the same classification scheme as divison algebras. But it seems that you are saying that there is six-dimensional normed algebra.

Comment: Only in situations where the 'norm' is zero for certain non-zero elements, so i guess in these situation you won't call it a norm. We still have a quadratic form though, that in the division algebra case over $\mathbb{R}$ is the square of the norm.

Comment: The split quaternion algebra is isomorphic to the algebra of two by two matrices where the analogue of the square of the norm is the determinant. Inside the two-by-two matrices we have the three dimensional (non-commutative) subalgebra of upper triangular matrices. If we realize the split octonions as the Dickson double of the split quaternion algebra then the Dickson double of the 3D subalg of upper triangular matrices sits inside it as a (nonassociative) 6-dimensional subalgebra

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$ the 'ordinary' octonions are waaaaaaay more famous than their split counterpart, due to being a division algebra. However when people started constructing these algebras over general fields the split ones more or less got their revenge as they exist over every field while division algebras do not.

Comment: I think I got that terminology from Springer and Veldkamp but my memory is not particularly good. Anyway, what I meant was an algebra with (nondegenerate?) quadratic form $Q$ such that $Q(xy) = Q(x)Q(y).$  And I thought that these are classified over (reasonable? all? most?) fields.

Comment: Anyway in the questin you mention 6 dimensional associative algebra that arises as Dickson double of a subalgebra of a normed algebra so I thought that this would be a normed algebra of strange dimension different from $1, 2, 4, 8.$ But then again, I never really looked into the classification of normed algebras so perhaps these do appear. I suggest you look into some thick books on Jordan algebras (Springer, Veldkamp, McCrimmon) as these classifications are often treated there.

Comment: Yes with that definition these are indeed normed algebras of stange dimension.

Comment: But not all strange normed algebras we can write down do appear as subalgebras of all bigger ones